# What is the significance of Census ACS columns with line numbers ending in ".5" or ".7"?

Tags: usa, us-census

In looking at the Census ACS data there are several columns that have line numbers ending in `.5` or `.7`. Their `table_ids` are duplicates of ones immediately before or after, making some import more difficult than it should be.

They seem to not have corresponding data in the distributed CSV data, either.

Comment: tangentially related : http://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/259/263

Comment: if you're trying to import acs into R, there's already code to import every file from every year here http://www.asdfree.com/2012/12/analyze-american-community-survey-acs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before seeing this, I actually verified this answer just earlier today with Paul Overberg, one of the leading Census journalists around: the "fractional line numbers" represent "headers": that is, they are labels that group together subsequent rows but which don't have values themselves.

His example was the "Median income in the past 12 months --" line in this: [image: segment of American Fact Finder view] (from http://factfinder2.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/ACS/11_1YR/B07411)